# Searching std::vector of class objects by class attribute (eg. name)

Tags: c++, vector, c++03

Is there any difference performance/safe-wise inspecting
vector elements using

1. for loop with iterators

vs.

2. std:find_if(...)?

   ---

**1. for loop**

```
// 1. for loop  
for (llvm::SmallVectorImpl<myClass>::const_iterator it = v.begin();
     it != v.end();
     ++it) {
    if (it->getName() == Name) {
        // found element
        // do smth...
        break;
    }
}
```

vs.

**2. std:find_if**

```
// 2. find if
llvm::SmallVectorImpl<myClass>::const_iterator it
    = std::find_if(v.begin(),
                   v.end(),
                   StringCheck<llvm::StringRef>(Name));
if (it != v.end()) {
    // found element
    // do smth...
}

// StringCheck defined in header...

template <class T>
struct StringCheck{
    StringCheck(const T &s) : s_(s) {}
    bool operator()(const myClass &obj) const
    {
        return obj.getName() == s_;
    }
private:
    const T &s_;
};
```

Comment: Nothing different "safe-wise". For performance you'll have to benchmark.

Comment: Ultimately, `std::find_if` will iterate the vector, so I guess no performance difference.

Comment: There [*may* be a performance difference either way.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36988833/4892076) Any such difference is small enough to be a premature optimization unless you've actually identified the loop as a bottleneck though, and in that case you'll want to do the profiling yourself.

Comment: Really the only difference I can see is the iterator loop will find all cases unless you use a break where `find_if` will implicitly stop at the first occurrence.

Comment: How do you think `std::find_if` is implemented - black magic? Actually, you don't need to guess - you can look at the implementation, it came with your compiler. You'll find a loop with iterators there.

Comment: According to Sean Parent's C++ seasoning, you should avoid using "raw for loops", and favor generic algorithms. The first major advantage of using an algorithm is readability: it's much easier to understand that you are searching for an object when you read `find_if` in the code rather than `for(...) { ... if( x == Y ) { ... } }`.

Comment: @KABoissonneault, easier said than done in pre-c++11. Otherwise you are correct.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I added a break; in the for loop, since my use case was to find just first match. Currently I am limited to c++03 usage but notes for c++11 are also interesting for me.

Comment: @J_T Then there should be no difference except for the people who feel that seeing `break` in a loop is code smell.

Comment: In case I need multiple matches what would be the correct way using <algorithms> ? Or simple for is the best shot then?

Answer (score 0):

Your for-loop continues iterating after a match is found.  This could be a good thing if multiple matches are possible and you want to run the code for each match, or a bad thing if you wanted to stop after a match is found and the match is found early in a large container.

Comment: In my use case I want to finish iterating after first match, so I added break; in the for loop.